# JRuby field_accessor final member

Tags: jruby

I have a java field that I want to subclass in jruby defined like so:

```
public abstract class FilterObjectStream<S, T> implements ObjectStream<T> {
    protected final ObjectStream<S> samples;
```

I then want to subclass this class and access this member, I have tried to access the protected final member like this, using field_accessor:

```
class NameSampleDataStream
  field_accessor :samples
end

class HtmlNameSampleDataStream < NameSampleDataStream
  def read
    token = self.samples.read()
    token
  end
end
```

I am getting an error message:

> SecurityError: Cannot change final
>   field 'samples'

I guess the exception answers the question but is there anyway that I can access this variable or is the game up?

I cannot change the java source unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try just doing "field_reader"? It's possible to set a final field accessible, but we don't do that for you, and what you want here is just a reader, right?